# How does Stackoverflow hide the URL of the new share on facebook etc

Tags: javascript

When you create a post , over in the Left hand side under the vote up and vote down, is a new share on twitter facebook and linkedin.

How do they do that, is it just using javascript ?

Or something far more clever than say:

This : http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/target_url_hiding.php

Comment: This does not belong on `meta`. Meta SO is about asking about asking: it's for talking about how we _use_ SO and whatnot. This question is just a programming question, and could just as well apply to _any_ website.

Comment: Sheesh do I look like a SO expert ? If I was I wouldnt be asking really would I, thanks for your Input... just marvellous, positive and proactive, great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `a` tag for the Facebook share does not have an `href` tag, therefore no URL is displayed when hovering over it by the browser.

They'll use JavaScript to capture the click on the `a` tag, and open a popup to complete the action.

### Edit:

**Psuedo JS code that isn't x-browser**

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == "fb-share") {
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Ahh well spotted, I missed that . Sweet. Be cool to see some pseudo code to have a play, but will carry on fiddling. Thankyou.

Comment: Cheers Matt, will have a Play.

Answer (score 1):

@Matt has already given a correct answer, but I'll add this to complement it. This is the code for the link on this page:

```
<a id="fb-share-7331333" class="fb-share" title="share link to this question on Facebook">share [fb]</a>
```

The image itself is applied via `background-image` and `background-position` CSS properties, from the sprite sheet found [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=4).

A click event handler is applied via jQuery, and what appears to be StackExchange's own JS library, to handle clicks on the element:

```
var shareUrl = "http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f7331333%2f790695";
var shareMsg = "How+does+Stackoverflow+hide+the+URL+of+the+new+share+on+facebook+etc";
StackExchange.share.facebook($("#fb-share-7331333"), shareUrl, shareMsg);
```

Comment: yer thanks, I had inspected with firebug. Also checked out the js they use, couldnt actually figure out how they fire the link tho. Thanks

Comment: @422 - It appears they use their own JS library, but I haven't dug any deeper than what I've now edited in to my answer.